# Account Owner name and Email id not Fetching the value in SOQL Query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, community, salesforce-id

Here is my code:

```
SELECT u.Contact.AccountId, u.Contact.Account.Owner.Name, u.Contact.Account.Owner.Email FROM User u WHERE u.id= :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: create formuale fields. You can easily retrieve it

Comment: Okay from Account Object?

Comment: yes you can create it

Comment: why its here not fetching the value (Account.Owner.Name) what is the issue? have any idea for this

Comment: I have tried the same & i didnt get..i provided that solution to you

Comment: What is u in your code ?

Comment: Does the user *have* a Contact? If `u.ContactId` is `null`, this is expected behavior, and I strongly suspect that's what's happening here.

Comment: Even I have that suspect as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula fields in Account level.

Here you need to create 2 formual fields one for owner Name & one for ownerEmail, Use that field for your query.It will work

Comment: okay my question is why are not working here. have a any idea?

Comment: I dont have any idea. we will see other answers..

Comment: okay thanks Annappa